# Función en C# a PHP

Tags: php

actualmente estoy implementando Shannon Fano en C# pero necesito llevarlo a PHP y no encuentro una solución, a continuación dejo las funciones. He intentado realizar la migración hacía PHP pero tengo problemas en algunos métodos de C#. Si alguien puede ayudarme o darme una pista estaré agradecido. Dejo el código original:

```
public struct letras
        {
            public int letra;
            public int frecuencia;
            public string codigo;
        };
        letras[] l = new letras[100];
        int n2 = 7;
        int[] le = new int[27];
        int[] let = new int[27];
        string[] codificacion = new string [26];

        void shanon(int pos1, int pos2)
        {

            int p;
            if ((pos1 + 1 - n2) == 0)
            {

            }

            else if ((pos2 - pos1) == 0)
            { 
            }
            else if (Math.Abs((pos1 - pos2)) == 1)
            {
                l[pos1].codigo = l[pos1].codigo + "0";
                l[pos2].codigo = l[pos2].codigo + "1";
            }
            else
            {
                int num1 = 0, ant = 0, num = 0, pos = 0, suma = 0, mitad = 0, me = 0, m = 0;
                int[] pruebas = new int[pos2 - pos1];
                for (int i = pos1; i <= pos2; i++)
                {
                    suma = suma + l[i].frecuencia;
                }
                mitad = suma / 2;
                for (int i = pos1; i <= pos2; i++)
                {

                    num1 = ant + l[i].frecuencia;
                    pos++;
                    for (int x = pos1; x <= pos2; x++)
                    {
                        num = num + l[pos + x].frecuencia;

                    }

                    pruebas[me] = Math.Abs(num1 - num);

                    if (num1 > mitad)
                    {
                        p = i;
                        for (int x = 0; x <= me; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = 0; y <= me; y++)
                            {
                                if (pruebas[x] < pruebas[y])
                                {
                                    if (pruebas[x] == 0)
                                    {
                                    }
                                    else if (pruebas[x] < pruebas[m])
                                    {
                                        m = x;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        int k = 0;

                        for (int o = pos1; o <= pos1 + m; o++)
                        {
                            l[o].codigo = l[o].codigo + "0";
                        }
                        for (int w = pos1 + m + 1; w <= pos2; w++)
                        {
                            l[w].codigo = l[w].codigo + "1";
                        }
                        if (m == 0)
                        {
                            num = 0;
                            ant = num1;
                            num1 = 0;
                            shanon(pos1 + 1, pos2);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            num = 0;
                            ant = num1;
                            num1 = 0;
                            shanon(pos1, pos1 + m);
                            m++;
                            num = 0;
                            ant = num1;
                            num1 = 0;
                            shanon(pos1 + m, pos2);
                        }
                        break;

                    }
                    num = 0;
                    ant = num1;
                    num1 = 0;
                    me++;
                }

            }
        }


        void letras1(int rango,int postx,string frase)
        {
            int post=1;
            int letra = rango;
            char l1;


            for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
            {
                foreach (int item in frase)
                {
                    if (item == letra)
                    {
                        le[i - 1]++;
                    }
                }
                if (le[i - 1] > 0)
                {

                    Label cb = new Label();
                    cb.AutoSize = true;
                    l1 = Convert.ToChar(letra);

                    cb.Text = "La Cantidad De " + l1 + " Es De : " + le[i - 1];
                    let[i - 1] = letra;
                    cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(postx, post * 25);
                    this.Controls.Add(cb);
                    post++;

                }
                letra = letra + 1;

            }


        }

        void orden()
        {
            int aux, aux1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= 25; x++)
                {
                    if (le[x] < le[x + 1])
                    {
                        aux = le[x + 1];
                        le[x + 1] = le[x];
                        le[x] = aux;

                        aux1 = let[x + 1];
                        let[x + 1] = let[x];
                        let[x] = aux1;

                    }
                }
            }
            int px = 15, py = 1,j=0;
            for (int x = 0; x <= 25; x++)
            {
                if (le[x] > 0)
                {
                    Label cb = new Label();
                    cb.AutoSize = true;
                    l[j].letra = let[x];
                    l[j].frecuencia = le[x];
                    cb.Text =Convert.ToChar(let[x]) + " = " + le[x];

                    cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(px, (py+4) * 25);
                    this.Controls.Add(cb);
                    py++;
                    j++;

                }
            }
            n2 = j;
            shanon(0, j);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                    Label lb = new Label();
                    lb.AutoSize = true;
                    lb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8 * i * px + 60, (5) * 22);
                    ListBox cb = new ListBox();
                    cb.AutoSize = true;
                    cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8*i * px + 60, (5) * 25);
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        lb.Text = "LETRAS";
                        for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)
                        {
                            cb.Items.Add(Convert.ToChar(l[x].letra));
                        }

                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        lb.Text = "FRECUENCIA:";
                        for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)
                        {
                            cb.Items.Add(l[x].frecuencia);
                        }
                    }
                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        lb.Text = "CODIGO:";
                         for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)
                        {
                        cb.Items.Add(l[x].codigo);
                        }
                    }
                    this.Controls.Add(cb);
                    this.Controls.Add(lb);
                    py++;
            }
            int sum = 0;
            int prom = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < py; i++)
            {
                sum = sum+le[i];

            }
            prom = sum / (py-1);

        }

if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text != "")
                {
                    this.Size = new Size(700, 333);
                    letras1(65, 340, textBox1.Text);
                    letras1(97, 500, textBox1.Text);
                    contar();
                    orden();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("DEBE DE INGRESAR UNA FRASE");
                }
            }
```

Cualquier idea es agradecida.

Comment: Saludos Alejandro, de PHP a C# existe una herramienta llamada Phpie https://www.peachpie.io/ te hará volar la imaginación. Bienvenido a SOes, recuerda ir por el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, esta herramienta me permite realizar de C# a PHP?

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido es al revéz. Revisa la documentación por si las dudas :D